# How do I display only one validation error in form?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I have several input fields in registration form. 
For example, there are 5 fields. 'Email' and "Phone Number" fields are wrong, I do not want to display both validation errors. I only want to check "Email" field and display Email error, if it will be correctly written on second try, only then 'Password' error message can appear.

Can I accomplish it with server-side validation only?

Screenshot: Both validation errors are displayed at the same time. 
[image]

Comment: FWIW, this is not something you should do. It's 100% not user-friendly to dispense errors piece meal. The user makes an error, gets a message, fixes that, then gets another error message, fixes that, then gets another message, etc. That's frustrating and will cause user drop-off. If you just don't want each field called out, use the validation summary instead of individual validation messages. Then, you'll just get a list of all errors at the top or something instead of on each individual field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically modify the `ModelState` and check the errors :

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{

   ....
}
else
{
    var flag = false;
    foreach (var modelState in ViewData.ModelState.Values)
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            modelState.Errors.Clear();
        }
        if (modelState.Errors.Count >0)
        {
            flag = true;
        }

        if (modelState.Errors.Count>1)
        {
            var firstError = modelState.Errors.First();
            modelState.Errors.Clear();
            modelState.Errors.Add(firstError);
        }

    }
}
return View("index", movie);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set maximum model validation errors to 1 in stratup, the validation process stops when max number is reached (200 by default):

```cs
services.AddMvc(options => 
{
    options.MaxModelValidationErrors = 1;
})
.SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

but in this case it will stop on the first error even if there is more than one validation error on the same property (e.g. password length is not valid, password must contain upper case letter, etc...).

If you need to show all errors at once for each property you will need another solution.

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: It doesn't display anything when I set MaxModelValidationErrors to 1